# how to write join query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created two beans User and VirtualDomain with many to many relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblUser")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private Set<VirtualDomain> virtualdomainset;
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "username", length = 50, nullable = false)
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
   @ManyToMany(targetEntity = VirtualDomain.class, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST},fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "tblUserDomainRel", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userid"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "domainid"))
    public Set<VirtualDomain> getVirtualdomainset() {
        return virtualdomainset;
    }

    public void setVirtualdomainset(Set<VirtualDomain> virtualdomainset) {
        this.virtualdomainset = virtualdomainset;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "tblVirtualDomain")
public class VirtualDomain  {
    private Long id;
    private String domainname;
    private Set<User> userset;
@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "domain_name")
public String getDomainname() {
    return domainname;
}

public void setDomainname(String domainname) {
    this.domainname = domainname;
}
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "virtualdomainset", targetEntity = User.class)

public Set<User> getUserset() {
    return userset;
}

public void setUserset(Set<User> userset) {
    this.userset = userset;
}
}
```

how to get data of user like username related to particular domain through hibernate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add to gid's answer, if for some reason you need to eagerly fetch an entites relations, then the join syntax would be join fetch.

```
from VirtualDomain vd join fetch vd.usersset u 
   where vd.domainname = 'example.com' and u.username like 'foo%'
```

Comment: hello Blake. please help me
When I used this query it is giving me the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.recover(Lantlr/RecognitionException;Lantlr/collections/impl/BitSet;)V

Comment: I've edited the query, there shouldn't have been any User in the query.

Comment: your edited query looks ok but I want only the username field from User so when i add select clause like select u.username it gives me error org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Comment: How about when reversing the query? 

select u.username from User u join u.virtualdomainset vd where vd.domainname = "example.com" and v.name like 'foo%'

Answer (score 4):

Always difficult to write HQL without a test system...but here we go:

```
select u from VirtualDomain vd join User vd.usersset u 
       where vd.domainname = 'example.com' and u.username like 'foo%'
```

Let me know how you get on.

One tip I often did prior to buying Intellji was to stop the app in the debugger and then use the immediate window to experiment with HQL.

The [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#queryhql-joins) on joins has always been a bit cryptic in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks but i can't understand tha last condition v.name like 'foo%'

Comment: That's the same kind of like clause that is found in SQL.

http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-LIKE.asp

Comment: just corrected the typo. as Blake says the like clause is just the same as the SQL one

Comment: When I used this query it is giving me the error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.recover(Lantlr/RecognitionException;Lantlr/collections/impl/BitSet;)V

Comment: that'll be an issue with the libraries that you have included in your application. I'm guessing that antlr.jar is the wrong version

Comment: I'm not going be able to help you much on this one. Other than to say , download the same version of hibernate again and manually check that you have exactly the same jars in your application as hibernate recommends.

Comment: any luck on that NoSuchMethod?